# Mysql query with pivot table and multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `sales` table, a `sale_staff` table, a `staff` table and an `offices` table.

We are selling properties, and I want to find out the numbers of sales per seller for X month and per office.

The pivot table looks like this

```
sale_id , staff_id , type
```

`type` can be either `seller` or `lister`, so I need a where clause for this.

The `sales` table has a FK to the `offices` table; `office_id`

What I have so far is this, its TOTALLY wrong I know, but that's why i'm here - i need to fix the sums and include the office name from the office table, so

```
 select st.first_name, st.last_name, office, count(*) as sold
from sales s, sale_staff ss
left join staff st 
on st.id = ss.staff_id
left join offices off
on off.id = s.office_id
where ss.`type` = 'lister' and
year(s.sale_date) = 2017 and
month(s.sale_date) = 12
group by st.id
```

Sales table is simply a property sale item, price, address, office_id.

Besides the error `unknown column s.office_id`, as I said, the sum value is incorrect anyway.  I'm really not experienced enough to understand this level of relationship joins and aggregating, any pointers please.

Basically I would like to simply see a resultset like

```
staff(seller) , count , office
 Mike         ,   12  ,  West
 Jim          ,   7   ,  East
 Fred         ,   3   ,  East
```

Edit: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dda63/1) in case that helps :) Will add some sample test data.

Comment: You can't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. Replace `from sales s, sale_staff ss` with an explicit join, as you did with your `left join`s

Comment: I'm not seeing the pivot part of your question here.  Please at least show us sample output for what you need.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen fair enough, updated

Comment: MIke can be a seller and a lister?

Comment: @P.Salmon correct, and there can be any number of sellers or listers per sale

Comment: @Strawberry i've added sqlfiddle if that was your reference

Comment: No. I think my reference is fairly self explicit. (138 people seem to agree, even if 6 don't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Your problem is because of the scoping rules around commas.

I would recommend:

```
select st.first_name, st.last_name, o.office, count(*) as sold
from staff st left join
     sale_staff ss
     on st.id = ss.staff_id join
     sales sa
     on sa.sale_id = ss.sale_id join
     offices o
     on o.id = s.office_id
where ss.`type` = 'lister' and
      s.sale_date >= '2017-12-01' and
      s.sale_date < '2018-01-01'
group by st.first_name, st.last_name, o.office;
```

I think this has the join condition correctly laid out, but it is hard to be sure without sample data and desired results.

Notes:

- `left join` is probably not necessary.  If it is, you should probably be starting with the staff table (to keep all staff).
- Qualify *all* column names.
- The `group by` includes all the non-aggregated columns in the `from`.  This is a good habit if you are learning SQL.
- The date comparisons are direct, without the use of functions.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time - i've fixed up some of the inconsistencies but am getting `out of sort memory`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfc715/5 , some small sample data included

Comment: ah scratch that - might be a sqlfiddle problem it seems its working in my client !  Thanks, will mark it correct shortly after i check the numbers :)